# MS Office Add-Ins, JavaScript and async/await

Tags: javascript, excel, async-await, office-js, office-addins

I am currently trying to get up to speed on writing an add-in for Excel and have done loads of reading around on the subject and am following this [excellent tutorial series](https://youtu.be/5d0Gm27wjQA?t=1372).

In the example, the presenter is using TypeScript, however, the current project I'm working on requires JavaScript.

I have replicated the example in a JavaScript Excel Web Add-In project in Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition instead of Script Lab and debugging the add-in on Desktop Excel seems to be working.

My problem comes in when using the async/await syntax of the TypeScript example in my JavaScript version, as the debugger throws a syntax error when I use it. Not having much experience with asynchronous programming in JS, I can see from the outset why async/await is much easier to use than nested callbacks or Promises. Chaining up **thens** looks torturous to me and I'd rather use async/await if I can.

What gave me the run around for a while was that JavaScript apparently **does** support async/await. So, the only thing I can think of now, is that the version of JavaScript that Excel is running is pre-ECMAScript 8. I can't find any Office.js add-in examples using async/await in JS. I don't know how the architecture all hangs together but if someone could confirm this, I'd appreciate it because I'd rather hear that there's a problem with the JavaScript version and I therefore can do nothing about it than continue under a false assumption and miss out on the chance to use async/await. [Sidenote: I'm also aware of OfficeExtension.Promise but that's still unsavory).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/asynchronous-programming-in-office-add-ins. I think MSoft has made a decent attempt at documentation here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, BigBen. Yeah, I skimmed over that during my research and noticed that the JS examples were using promises while the TS versions were using async/await. I was hoping that this was a JS version issue and that someone out there had hacked a way to using ES8 in Office Add-ins (assuming that JS version is the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting syntax errors from await/async, then you are probably testing on a version of Office that uses IE as the browser. (For information on which browser is used on various versions of Office,  see [Browsers used by Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins).) IE does not natively support any version of JavaScript past ES5, so it doesn't recognize async/await (or Promises). To use these features of ES6+ when the browser is IE, you need to load a polyfill or else use a transpiler like tsc or babel to transpile the ES6+ code down to ES5 code.

Comment: OK, thanks Rick. It seems then that my nose was sniffing in the right direction. In my case, I'm debugging using Desktop Excel but presumably the same reasoning applies; ie. Office 365 is running a pre-ES8 JS engine. Sad. Looks like I'm going to have to just bite the bullet and soldier on with messy promises.